# Extracting image region within boundary

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I have to do a project using 2D CT images and segment liver and tumor in it using Matlab(only). Initially i have to segment liver region alone. I use region growing for liver segmentation. It gets seed point as input.

The output is an image with a boundary for liver region. Now I need the region that is surrounded by the boundary alone.

My program has a main program and a regionGrowing.m function. As I'm a new user am not allowed to post images. If you do need images I will mail you. Kindly help me.

```
  % mainreg.m

  IR=imread('nfliver5.jpg');
  figure, imshow(IR), hold all
  poly = regionGrowing(IR,[],15,1200); % click somewhere inside the liver
  plot(poly(:,1), poly(:,2), 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', [1 1 1])
```

---

```
%regionGrowing.m

function [P, J] = regionGrowing(cIM, initPos, thresVal, maxDist, tfMean, tfFillHoles, tfSimplify)
% REGIONGROWING Region growing algorithm for 2D/3D grayscale images
%
% Syntax:
%   P = regionGrowing();
%   P = regionGrowing(cIM);
%   P = regionGrowing(cIM, initPos)
%   P = regionGrowing(..., thresVal, maxDist, tfMean, tfFillHoles, tfSimpl)
%   [P, J] = regionGrowing(...);
%
% Inputs:
%          cIM: 2D/3D grayscale matrix                      {current image}
%      initPos: Coordinates for initial seed position     {ginput position}
%     thresVal: Absolute threshold level to be included     {5% of max-min}
%      maxDist: Maximum distance to the initial position in [px]      {Inf}
%       tfMean: Updates the initial value to the region mean (slow) {false}
%  tfFillHoles: Fills enclosed holes in the binary mask              {true}
%   tfSimplify: Reduces the number of vertices {true, if dpsimplify exists}
%
% Outputs:
%   P: VxN array (with V number of vertices, N number of dimensions)
%      P is the enclosing polygon for all associated pixel/voxel
%   J: Binary mask (with the same size as the input image) indicating
%      1 (true) for associated pixel/voxel and 0 (false) for outside
%   
% Examples:
%   % 2D Example
%   load example
%   figure, imshow(cIM, [0 1500]), hold all
%   poly = regionGrowing(cIM, [], 300); % click somewhere inside the lungs
%   plot(poly(:,1), poly(:,2), 'LineWidth', 2)
%   
%   % 3D Example
%   load mri
%   poly = regionGrowing(squeeze(D), [66,55,13], 60, Inf, [], true, false);
%   plot3(poly(:,1), poly(:,2), poly(:,3), 'x', 'LineWidth', 2)
%
% Requirements:
%   TheMathWorks Image Processing Toolbox for bwboundaries() and axes2pix()
%   Optional: Line Simplification by Wolfgang Schwanghart to reduce the 
%             number of polygon vertices (see the MATLAB FileExchange)
%
% Remarks:
%   The queue is not preallocated and the region mean computation is slow.
%   I haven't implemented a preallocation nor a queue counter yet for the
%   sake of clarity, however this would be of course more efficient.
%
% Author:
%   Daniel Kellner, 2011, braggpeaks{}googlemail.com
%   History: v1.00: 2011/08/14


% error checking on input arguments
if nargin > 7
    error('Wrong number of input arguments!')
end

if ~exist('cIM', 'var')
    himage = findobj('Type', 'image');
    if isempty(himage) || length(himage) > 1
        error('Please define one of the current images!')
    end

    cIM = get(himage, 'CData');
end

if ~exist('initPos', 'var') || isempty(initPos)
    himage = findobj('Type', 'image');
    if isempty(himage)
        himage = imshow(cIM, []);
    end

    % graphical user input for the initial position
    p = ginput(1);

    % get the pixel position concerning to the current axes coordinates
    initPos(1) = round(axes2pix(size(cIM, 2), get(himage, 'XData'), p(2)));
    initPos(2) = round(axes2pix(size(cIM, 1), get(himage, 'YData'), p(1)));
end

if ~exist('thresVal', 'var') || isempty(thresVal)
    thresVal = double((max(cIM(:)) - min(cIM(:)))) * 0.05;
end

if ~exist('maxDist', 'var') || isempty(maxDist)
    maxDist = Inf;
end

if ~exist('tfMean', 'var') || isempty(tfMean)
    tfMean = false;
end

if ~exist('tfFillHoles', 'var')
    tfFillHoles = true;
end

if isequal(ndims(cIM), 2)
    initPos(3) = 1;
elseif isequal(ndims(cIM),1) || ndims(cIM) > 3
    error('There are only 2D images and 3D image sets allowed!')
end

[nRow, nCol, nSli] = size(cIM);

if initPos(1) < 1 || initPos(2) < 1 ||...
   initPos(1) > nRow || initPos(2) > nCol
    error('Initial position out of bounds, please try again!')
end

if thresVal < 0 || maxDist < 0
    error('Threshold and maximum distance values must be positive!')
end

if ~isempty(which('dpsimplify.m'))
    if ~exist('tfSimplify', 'var')
        tfSimplify = true;
    end
    simplifyTolerance = 1;
else
    tfSimplify = false;
end


% initial pixel value
regVal = double(cIM(initPos(1), initPos(2), initPos(3)));

% text output with initial parameters
disp(['RegionGrowing Opening: Initial position (' num2str(initPos(1))...
      '|' num2str(initPos(2)) '|' num2str(initPos(3)) ') with '...
      num2str(regVal) ' as initial pixel value!'])

% preallocate array
J = false(nRow, nCol, nSli);

% add the initial pixel to the queue
queue = [initPos(1), initPos(2), initPos(3)];


%%% START OF REGION GROWING ALGORITHM
while size(queue, 1)
  % the first queue position determines the new values
  xv = queue(1,1);
  yv = queue(1,2);
  zv = queue(1,3);

  % .. and delete the first queue position
  queue(1,:) = [];

  % check the neighbors for the current position
  for i = -1:1
    for j = -1:1
      for k = -1:1

        if xv+i > 0  &&  xv+i <= nRow &&...          % within the x-bounds?
           yv+j > 0  &&  yv+j <= nCol &&...          % within the y-bounds?          
           zv+k > 0  &&  zv+k <= nSli &&...          % within the z-bounds?
           any([i, j, k])       &&...      % i/j/k of (0/0/0) is redundant!
           ~J(xv+i, yv+j, zv+k) &&...          % pixelposition already set?
           sqrt( (xv+i-initPos(1))^2 +...
                 (yv+j-initPos(2))^2 +...
                 (zv+k-initPos(3))^2 ) < maxDist &&...   % within distance?
           cIM(xv+i, yv+j, zv+k) <= (regVal + thresVal) &&...% within range
           cIM(xv+i, yv+j, zv+k) >= (regVal - thresVal) % of the threshold?

           % current pixel is true, if all properties are fullfilled
           J(xv+i, yv+j, zv+k) = true; 

           % add the current pixel to the computation queue (recursive)
           queue(end+1,:) = [xv+i, yv+j, zv+k];

           if tfMean
               regVal = mean(mean(cIM(J > 0))); % --> slow!
           end

        end        
      end
    end  
  end
end
%%% END OF REGION GROWING ALGORITHM


% loop through each slice, fill holes and extract the polygon vertices
P = [];
for cSli = 1:nSli
    if ~any(J(:,:,cSli))
        continue
    end

    % use bwboundaries() to extract the enclosing polygon
    if tfFillHoles
        % fill the holes inside the mask
        J(:,:,cSli) = imfill(J(:,:,cSli), 'holes');    
        B = bwboundaries(J(:,:,cSli), 8, 'noholes');
    else
        B = bwboundaries(J(:,:,cSli));
    end

    newVertices = [B{1}(:,2), B{1}(:,1)];

    % simplify the polygon via Line Simplification
    if tfSimplify
        newVertices = dpsimplify(newVertices, simplifyTolerance);        
    end

    % number of new vertices to be added
    nNew = size(newVertices, 1);

    % append the new vertices to the existing polygon matrix
    if isequal(nSli, 1) % 2D
        P(end+1:end+nNew, :) = newVertices;
    else                % 3D
        P(end+1:end+nNew, :) = [newVertices, repmat(cSli, nNew, 1)];
    end
end

% text output with final number of vertices
disp(['RegionGrowing Ending: Found ' num2str(length(find(J)))...
      ' pixels within the threshold range (' num2str(size(P, 1))...
      ' polygon vertices)!'])
```

Comment: I have cleaned up your questions somewhat and given it what I think is a relevant title. Keep it to the point. If truly necessary, put the images somewhere online and we can add them to your question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a binary image of the boundary of the kidney and now need to set the inside of the boundary to 1s. To do this, you can use the [imfill()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imfill.html) function with the 'holes' setting on.

```
BW2 = imfill(BW,'holes');
```

EDIT: Looking at the code, it seems that it does what you want already.

```
% Outputs:
%   J: Binary mask (with the same size as the input image) indicating
%      1 (true) for associated pixel/voxel and 0 (false) for outside
```

so you just need to get the second output as well:

```
  IR=imread('nfliver5.jpg');
  figure, imshow(IR), hold all
  [poly im] = regionGrowing(IR,[],15,1200); % click somewhere inside the liver
  imshow(im,[])
```

Now `im` is a binary image with your segmented region.

EDIT2:

Once you have the binary image `im`, you can simply use element-wise multiplication to remove all parts of the orignal image outside the segmented region.

```
SEG = IR.*im;
imshow(SEG,[])
```

EDIT3:

For 3D images, you need to specify the coordinates manually, and not by using the mouse. This is because the mouse only gives us 2 coordinates (x and y) and you need 3 (x,y and z). So just find the coordinates you need by looking at the image, and then choosing an appropriate z coordinate.

```
%Example coordinates, 
coordinates = [100 100 5] 
poly = regionGrowing(squeeze(IR), coordinates, 60, Inf, [], true, false);
```

Comment: Thanks Gaul. But when I try this, I get only the same input as output.I wrote as BW=imread('nfliver5.jpg');BW2=imfill(BW,'holes'); Then i displayed the images.where nfliver5.jpg is the output image within boundary. Actually I need only the region surrounded by the white boundary and have to remove the remaining part of image that is outside the boundary.

Comment: For imfill to work it has to be a binary image, but never mind. The algorithm already does this for you. Look at my edited answer.

Comment: U are right. but kindly check out the following pdf     http://www.ijcaonline.org/casct/number1/SPE34T.pdf   .See the output images Fig 6 and Fig 7 in it. Now am getting an output similar to that shown in Fig 6(using region growing). What I need is the Fig 7. Because I need to further process it to extract tumor also(just like Fig 8). Kindly help.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It worked. I got the liver separately. I have one more problem. When I use 3d ct images, I changed the main program as '  poly = regionGrowing(squeeze(IR), [], 60, Inf, [], true, false);
  plot3(poly(:,1), poly(:,2), poly(:,3), 'x', 'LineWidth', 2)' When I run the program I get the following error: ??? Attempted to access initPos(3); index out of bounds because numel(initPos)=2.

Error in ==> regionGrowing at 125
regVal = double(cIM(initPos(1), initPos(2), initPos(3)))      Kindly help me. Consider the 3d image at the following link:

Comment: The link for the image is    http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=liver+ct+images&hl=en&sa=X&biw=1366&bih=549&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=m7VRIg2BNA7yGM:&imgrefurl=http://doralmri.com/CT.html&docid=sHKZJi37VmpTxM&imgurl=http://doralmri.com/images/CT%252520Liver.jpg&w=300&h=220&ei=EtFMT-2TJ8PyrQes35m7Dw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=145&vpy=225&dur=548&hovh=176&hovw=240&tx=135&ty=73&sig=112248589071553736118&page=3&tbnh=159&tbnw=233&start=39&ndsp=15&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:39

Comment: If you are happy with the answer to the orignal question you should accept it. For your second question, see my edit answer.

Comment: I dont get the error now sir. Thanks for the explanation. I will now have to find out the correct coordinates. I think its a tedious job. Is ther any short method to find it, sir?

Comment: A quick way to find the coordinates is by looking at the image using imshow() and then using the data cursor from the panel (next to zoom, etc..) to get the coordinates.

Comment: Thank you sir. But each time I give values, I get the whole abdominal region surrounded by white boundary. I don't get the accurate segmentation as I got in 2D images.What to do sir?

Comment: You have to adjust the parameters of the algorithm to suit your problem. This means that you have to understand how the algorithm works. But segmentation is a difficult problem, and one method does not always work for all problems.

Comment: Sir. I have posted a new question in my profile. Kindly check it out sir.

Comment: Sir, I did fuzzy c means for tumor extraction from the obtained region. But insted of getting the tumor as white region, I get all the surrounding regions as white. So, I tried complementing the image using imcomplement(). But as the background was originally dark, now I get the entire background as white. Can you kindly help me?

Comment: Just use imclearborder() to remove all white structures connected to the border of the image. But since your segmentation is inperfect you should probably smooth the image with a median filter or something before you do do imcomplement().

Comment: Sir, where exactly I have to use imclearborder? In the binary mask of the region growing output?(I tried it sir,but got no change in output).Or after segmentation, I have to use median filter. Then do imcomplement() and then imclearborder(). Am I telling the correct order of steps sir?

Comment: Thank you sir. It worked. I used medfilt2 to filter the region growing output. Then did imcomplement. Then imclearborder. Then to that image I applied fcm. It gave the output sir. I have uploaded the 2 images(ie. after imclearborder and after fcm). There are certain unwanted dots in the images. How to remove it sir? I thought of trying morphological operations. Then do the element wise multiplication as you said earlier. If what I'm telling is correct, then which morphological operation will be helpful in my case sir?Which structuring element sir?

Comment: The uploaded images are added to the question sir.

Comment: Just try a couple. imdilate() might work. You can also remove small noise pixels by using bwareaopen(). Or you can try some heavier smoothing. It is your work, so it is better if you come up with the solution yourself.