# Fuzzy C Means for tumor segmentation using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a segmented liver. I need to segment the tumor in it. I used the FCM method. It is a 3 level FCM thresholding. When I apply it to the images, I need the tumor region(the region that is darker than the remaining parts) alone to get segmented. But am getting the reverse. All the region surrounding the tumor gets segmented. Kindly help me out. The program has two files, `testfcmthresh.m` and a function `fcmthresh.m`

The input 'segmented liver(using region growing)' and the FCM output image:

[image: input segemented liver]
[image: output FCM image]
[from here](http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.2482420198768.89088.1800503467&type=1&l=dfe444754f)

I tried complementing the image obtained by using `imcomplement()` But I got the entire background also as white, since the background was originally dark. Kindly help me out.

[image: after imclearborder]
[image: after fcm]

```
function [bw,level]=fcmthresh(IM,sw)
%FCMTHRESH Thresholding by 3-class fuzzy c-means clustering
%  [bw,level]=fcmthresh(IM,sw) outputs the binary image bw and threshold level of
%  image IM using a 3-class fuzzy c-means clustering. It often works better
%  than Otsu's methold which outputs larger or smaller threshold on
%  fluorescence images.
%  sw is 0 or 1, a switch of cut-off position.
%  sw=0, cut between the small and middle class
%  sw=1, cut between the middle and large class
%
%  Contributed by Guanglei Xiong (xgl99@mails.tsinghua.edu.cn)
%  at Tsinghua University, Beijing, China.

% check the parameters
if (nargin<1)
    error('You must provide an image.');
elseif (nargin==1)
    sw=0;
elseif (sw~=0 && sw~=1)
    error('sw must be 0 or 1.');
end

data=reshape(IM,[],1);
[center,member]=fcm(data,3);
[center,cidx]=sort(center);
member=member';
member=member(:,cidx);
[maxmember,label]=max(member,[],2);
if sw==0
    level=(max(data(label==1))+min(data(label==2)))/2;
else
    level=(max(data(label==2))+min(data(label==3)))/2;
end
bw=im2bw(IM,level);
```

---

```
%testfcmthresh.m

clear;clc;
im=imread('mliver3.jpg');
fim=mat2gray(im);
level=graythresh(fim);
bwfim=im2bw(fim,0.1);
[bwfim0,level0]=fcmthresh(fim,0);
[bwfim1,level1]=fcmthresh(fim,1);
subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(fim);title('Original');
subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(bwfim);title(sprintf('Otsu,level=%f',level));
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(bwfim0);title(sprintf('FCM0,level=%f',level0));
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(bwfim1);title(sprintf('FCM1,level=%f',level1));
% imwrite(bwfim1,'fliver6.jpg');
```

Comment: Can we have pictures of the tumor and liver?

Comment: I'm a new user. So I cant post image here. If you give me your id I will send it to that. Thanks in advance.  P.S. My project is using Matlab

Comment: Upload them somewhere and put the links in the question. I'll edit the images in.

Comment: I have edited my question (added the link for the images). There will be 2 images. The input 'segmented liver image' and the final 'fcm output' image. Kindly check it out.

Comment: what about reversing/inverting the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for my question has been told by Ghaul in my previous question ['Extracting image region within boundary'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9443215/461597). If any one needs to refer, kindly go through the comments by Ghaul in that.Thank you.